# Why does my application take two sessionIDs?

Tags: asp.net, session

In a web application, I need the SessionID for some reason, so, I save it in the database. the application does two redirects before it starts, and I found that it acquires two SessionIDs. The second one remains.

Why this behavior ? Any idea? How can I prevent that to save in the DB one record.

Sorry because I can't post code, it's compound with another logic.

Comment: why do you need the sessionid?

Answer (score 2):

There's a million possible reasons for losing / re-starting your session.  Without your code, its difficult to offer advice.

One thing you can try on your own is to use the Session_End event in your global.asax file, as long as you're using inProc session.  Put some code in there to have it tell you when the session ends, so you can track-down the problem / what's causing it to end in your application.

Another think you can look at is your method of redirecting.  Make sure you're preserving the session, like this: Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx", false).

Comment: I put code to write in Log when the session is end, but so far, nothing is written. Seems it fires when the session is time out. doesn't it?

Comment: Session_End fires whenever the session ends -- doesn't matter it it's because of timeout, or you call session.abandon, or whatever.  BUT...it only works if your session (in your web.config) is using inProc memory.  If you're using a state-server, etc., it doesn't work.

Comment: Also look into response.redirect and server.transfer.  Ammended my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you might not be putting anything into your first session.  By default, you'll get a new sessionID on each postback ***unless*** you put something in the session.